# Move nested folders and files to new location using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have 200 users whose files and folders all reside in a random number of nested folders and files in their user area on our server. The only guarantee is that each user has the following three folders. `My Music`, `My Pictures`, `My Videos`.

I would like to write a batch file that moves:

`H:\My Music` (and all its contents) to `H:\Music`

`H:\My Pictures` (and all its contents) to `H:\Pictures`

`H:\My Videos` (and all its contents) to `H:\Video`

And finally all their remaining files and folders to the following to `H:\Documents`

I have been fiddling with the following command and although it works and traverses the whole nested folder structure, *it is limited to files and folder without spaces*. I assume I need to add a `token delims` statement, but I can't get the syntax right.

```
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:\My Music" /b') DO MOVE H:\My Music\%%a H:\Documents\Music

FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:\My Pictures" /b') DO MOVE H:\My Pictures\%%a H:\Documents\Pictures

FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:\My Videos" /b') DO MOVE H:\My Videos\%%a H:\Documents\Videos

FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:" /b') DO MOVE H:\%%a H:\Documents
```

How do I deal with the spaces in the file and folder names?

I know I can achieve this with XCOPY, but space is an issue. More importantly time is extremely limited. I intend to get all users to run this script, during a 30 minute training session. With most users having several GB's of files XCOPY would take more time than is available during a 30 minute session.

Comment: Why not the simple `move H:\My Music\* H:\Documents\Music\`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplifu your code like this :

```
@echo off&cls
set "$Drive=h:\"
set "$folder=music Pictures Videos"

for %%a in (%$folder%) do echo MOVE "%$DRIVE%my %%a" "%$drive%Documents\%%a"
pause
```

I put an echo before the move that you can test if tje output is ok for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around names that contain spaces.

Something like this should work:

```
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:\My Music" /b') DO MOVE "H:\My Music\%%a" H:\Documents\Music

FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:\My Pictures" /b') DO MOVE "H:\My Pictures\%%a" H:\Documents\Pictures

FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:\My Videos" /b') DO MOVE "H:\My Videos\%%a" H:\Documents\Videos

FOR /f %%a IN ('dir "H:" /b') DO MOVE "H:\%%a" H:\Documents
```